# Скрытие div по условию

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, hide

Есть такой код, скрывает элементы по условию совпадения класса и id

```
$("[id ^= Block1_][class = t-widget t-grid]").bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
  $("[id ^= Block2_][id $= CaptionContainer]").closest("tr").hide();
});
```

структура DOM

```
<div class="t-widget t-grid" id="Block1_d1db1ee2292a49628848ed859c574472_Tc1b6e30bm6c41m48fcm84b7mec17247d8e69" provider="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
 <div class="t-widget t-grid" id="Block1_d1db1ee2292a49628848ed859c574472_Tc1b6e30bm6c41m48fcm84b7mec17247d8e69__Block2_ac66d2b465a3464791cb5e3b1ed56294_5556_tbl" provider="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
 <tr class="t-no-data"><td colspan="3">Нет данных для отображения</td></tr>
 <tr> <td> </tr>
```

---

`class="t-no-data"` может быть, а может и нет.

Как написать условие, что если в элементе `Block2` есть `tr` с классом `"t-no-data"`, то выполнить код вначале, и если нет - то ничего не делать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте форматирование.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("[id*='_Block2_'] .t-no-data").length) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить перебрать элементы и скрыть на ходу:

```
$('.t-widget').each(function (){
if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('_Block2_')>=0 && $(this).children('tr').hasClass('t-no-data'))
{
$(this).hide();
}
});
```